# how to thymeleaf th:each number variable input image src?

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to show image in li tags using thymeleaf th:each.
I have tried to enter variable value of number into image src but image is not displayed.
how to thymeleaf th:each number variable input image src?

try code:

```html
<th:block th:each="num: ${#numbers.sequence(1,22)}">
<li>
<img th:src="@{/images/sub/logo/company + ${num} + .jpg}">
</li>
</th:block>

and 

<li th:each="num: ${#numbers.sequence(1,22)}">
<img th:src="@{/images/sub/logo/company + ${num} + .jpg}">
</li>
```

error:
http://localhost:8090/****/images/sub/logo/company%20+%20$%7Bnum%7D%20+%20.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the standard url syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html).

```
<li th:each="num: ${#numbers.sequence(1,22)}">
  <img th:src="@{/images/sub/logo/company{i}.jpg(i=${num})}">
</li>
```